# sending cgpoint aka struck cgpoint to parameter of incompatible type UIOffset aka struck UIOffset

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode5

I download the sample code of apple " DynamicsCatalog.xcodeproj" where I have this problem

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIDynamicAnimator* animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
    UICollisionBehavior* collisionBehavior = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.square1]];

    CGPoint squareCenterPoint = CGPointMake(self.square1.center.x, self.square1.center.y - 100.0);
    CGPoint attachmentPoint = CGPointMake(-25.0, -25.0);
    /*
     By default, an attachment behavior uses the center of a view. By using a small offset, we get a more interesting effect which will cause the view to have rotation movement when dragging the attachment.
     */
    UIAttachmentBehavior *attachmentBehavior = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.square1 point:attachmentPoint attachedToAnchor:squareCenterPoint];

    collisionBehavior.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;

    // Show visually the attachment points
    self.redSquare.center = attachmentBehavior.anchorPoint;
    self.blueSquare.center = CGPointMake(25.0, 25.0);

    [animator addBehavior:attachmentBehavior];
    self.animator = animator;

    self.attachmentBehavior = attachmentBehavior;
}
```

where I'm replacing this line:

```
UIAttachmentBehavior *attachmentBehavior = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.square1 attachedToAnchor:squareCenterPoint];
```

with this line:

```
 UIAttachmentBehavior *attacheMentBehavior = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.square1 offsetFromCenter:attachmentPoint attachedToAnchor:squareCenterPoint];
```

but I'm getting this error:

sending cgpoint aka struck cgpoint to parameter of incompatible type UIOffset aka struck UIOffset

I'll really appreciate if you can please let me know what I'm doing wrong or how can fix this.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are passing `attachmentPoint` which is of `CGPoint` type. You must make a `UIOffset` type of variable and pass that variable instead of your `attachmentPoint`.

Comment: I'm confuse. Can you please tellme how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do this way -

```
   UIOffset attachmentPoint = UIOffsetMake (-25.0, -25.0);

  UIAttachmentBehavior *attachmentBehavior = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc]
                                                initWithItem:self.square1
                                                offsetFromCenter:attachmentPoint
                                                attachedToAnchor:squareCenterPoint];
```

hope this helps!!